# Finding solution to Cauchy prob. in Matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, ode, differential-equations

I need some help with finding solution to Cauchy problem in Matlab.
The problem: 
y''+10xy = 0, y(0) = 7, y '(0) = 3
Also I need to plot the graph. 
I wrote some code but, I'm not sure whether it's correct or not. Particularly in function section.
Can somebody check it? If it's not correct, where I made a mistake?
Here is separate function in other .m file:

```
function dydx = funpr12(x,y) 
    dydx = y(2)+10*x*y 
end
```

Main:

```
%% Cauchy problem
clear all, clc
xint = [0,5]; % interval
y0 = [7;3]; % initial conditions
% numerical solution using ode45
sol = ode45(@funpr12,xint,y0);
xx = [0:0.01:5]; % vector of x values
y = deval(sol,xx); % vector of y values
plot(xx,y(1,:),'r', 'LineWidth',3)
legend('y1(x)')
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y(x)')
```

I get this graph:

[image: Here is the graph]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ode45`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html) and its related ilk are only designed to solve **first-order** differential equations which are of the form `y' = ...`.  You need to do a bit of work if you want to solve second-order differential questions.

Specifically, you'll have to represent your problem as a **system** of first-order differential equations.  You currently have the following ODE:

```
 y'' + 10xy = 0, y(0) = 7, y'(0) = 3
```

If we rearrange this to solve for `y''`, we get:

```
y'' = -10xy, y(0) = 7, y'(0) = 3
```

Next, you'll want to use two variables... call it `y1` and `y2`, such that:

```
y1 = y
y2 = y'
```

The way you have built your code for `ode45`, the initial conditions that you specified are exactly this - the guess using `y` and its first-order guess `y'`.

Taking the derivative of each side gives:

```
y1' = y'
y2' = y''
```

Now, doing some final substitutions we get this final system of first-order differential equations:

```
y1' = y2
y2' = -10*x*y1
```

If you're having trouble seeing this, simply remember that `y1 = y`, `y2 = y'` and finally `y2' = y'' = -10*x*y = -10*x*y1`.  Therefore, you now need to build your function so that it looks like this:

```
function dydx = funpr12(x,y) 
    y1 = y(2);
    y2 = -10*x*y(1);
    dydx = [y1 y2];
end
```

Remember that the vector `y` is a two element vector which represents the value of `y` and the value of `y'` respectively at each time point specified at `x`.  I would also argue that making this an anonymous function is cleaner.  It requires less code:

```
funpr12 = @(x,y) [y(2); -10*x*y(1)];
```

Now go ahead and solve it (using your code):

```
%%// Cauchy problem
clear all, clc

funpr12 = @(x,y) [y(2); -10*x*y(1)]; %// Change
xint = [0,5]; % interval
y0 = [7;3]; % initial conditions
% numerical solution using ode45
sol = ode45(funpr12,xint,y0); %// Change - already a handle

xx = [0:0.01:5]; % vector of x values
y = deval(sol,xx); % vector of y values
plot(xx,y(1,:),'r', 'LineWidth',3)
legend('y1(x)')
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y(x)')
```

Take note that the output when simulating the solution to the differential equation by `deval` will be a two column matrix. The first column is the solution to the system while the second column is the derivative of the solution. As such, you'll want to plot the first column, which is what the plot syntax is doing.

I get this plot now:

[image]

Comment: @rayryeng Thank you for your big help and explanation, Everything is good. I have one question, how I can print the values of dydx? Because right now it prints only the graph.

Comment: @Bestinthe The vector `y` given from the call to `deval` stores the solution to the differential equation at each time point.  You can do this: `disp([xx(:), y(:)])` after you plot the graph.  This will show you the time points on the left column and the associated solution on the right.  BTW, you are most welcome.  Good luck!

Comment: I'm getting this error: Error using horzcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

Comment: @Bestinthe Apologies, it should be `disp([xx(:) y(1,:).'])`.  I forgot for a moment we will solving a system of differential equations.  The first column of `y` should be the solution while the second column is its derivative.

Comment: @rayryeng Fantastic, once again Thank you very much!

Comment: @Bestinthe It was my pleasure.  Good luck!

Comment: @Bestinthe If I can offer one more piece of advice, try doing `format long g;` before the `disp` command.  This will increase the number of digits of precision for displaying your results if accuracy is critical.